# the MainActivity show the up icon(the left-facing caret)

Tags: android

I am working under an android application which I want to provide the  Up Navigation, follow the [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html), I made the following configuration:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@style/OverlayActionBarTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.RouteActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ui.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SearchPoiActivity" android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ui.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.PoiListActivity" android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ui.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

However I have to questions here:

1 The repeat codes

As you can see I have to add the following xml for each activity, is it possible to declare it once?

```
    android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".ui.MainActivity"/>
```

2 The main activity of my application `.ui.MainActivity` have the `up` icon !

Tha's to say even I enter my application the first time and at the `MainActivity`, the `left-facing caret` is visible. I do not think this is normal.

Then I wonder does I miss anything?